# Drawing Nodes with dynamic color in PGFplot axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've got difficulties to understand where my code breaks. Eventually, I would like to draw three dots with a color depending on the x value within a axis environment. I have tried multiple ways, but I have given two below. Could you please explain why these examples won't work?

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.0, 1.0    
3.0, 2.2
4.0, 3.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=latex]

\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=5.5,
ymin=-0.1,
ymax=5.1,
axis background/.style={}
]
    \csvreader[no head]{data.csv}{1=\first, 2=\second}%
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ccc}{\first*20};
        \colorlet{tempcolor}{red!\ccc!black}

        % does not run
        %\node[draw, circle, color=tempcolor] at (\first,\second){ok};

        % runs but shows only one node
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xxx}{\first};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yyy}{\second};
        \node[draw, circle, color=tempcolor] at (\xxx,\yyy){ok};
    };  
\end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different method that does work. It relies on `visualization depends on` to calculate `\ccc`. The nodes are placed using `\addplot` with `mark=text`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.0, 1.0    
3.0, 2.2
4.0, 3.0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, >=latex]

\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=5.5,
ymin=-0.1,
ymax=5.1,
visualization depends on=x*20 \as \ccc
]

\addplot [
   only marks,
   mark=text,
   text mark as node=true,
   text mark style={red!\ccc!black,draw,circle},
   text mark=ok
] table[col sep=comma] {data.csv};

\end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```